# Does contributing to Review Queues help to lift a question ban?

Tags: support, feature-request, review-queues, post-ban

I have a question ban, but have been regularly editing, answering, commenting, voting, flagging, and now also reviewing. I know just about everything else can help against a question ban, but what about reviewing?

Reviewing is probably *the* most impactful to keeping this website clean (other than just good question/answer writing), so it would make sense if it did help. But how much? I viewed [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) meta thread, but it didn't say anything about reviews, although it *did* mention the exact rules aren't public

If it isn't, it needs to be. The people who put in the time to review but can't even ask questions need to be unbanned, because they actually help the site.

*This also all goes for answer bans*

Comment: Generally, positive contributions to the site will help with getting out of a post-ban. At least, lots of good answers can get you out of a question ban. I don't know if *reviewing* specifically will help, but I presume it does. *How much* reviewing is required will not be made public, but I expect it to be a lot. Fixing your questions (if you have a question ban) is probably the most straightforward way to get out of that ban though.

Comment: It doesn't matter "they actually help the site". What matters is that they prove they are able to provide quality posts (either question or answers, depending on the type of ban)

Comment: @yivi How will the system know if someone with a question ban can ask good questions or if someone with an answer ban can write good answers? To review is to know what makes a good question/answer, no matter what queue you're in.

Comment: They can prove in two ways: By editing previous posts so they are better received, by posting new posts then the system gives them more opportunities (the q-ban allows you to post a new question every six months, the a-ban is different and more restrictive; can't really remember the details).

Comment: Reated MSE post: [Does reviewing posts help remove a post ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328881)

Comment: @yivi What if your ban is mostly from duplicates (Nope not getting into how I feel about duplicates right now)? You can't "fix" a duplicate post. And we've all seen just how many duplicates are posted. Maybe this'll help: When you're going through the first-post queue, you are often editing someone's low quality question/answer into something at least good enough for other user's to answer. Clearly those people can write a good post, given they can at least edit a low-quality post to one.

Comment: Posting duplicates doesn’t result in a ban. Posting badly received question does.

Comment: @yivi the vast majority of the time, duplicates are badly received. Usually they are downvoted significantly before they are closed. 

You also avoided the second part of my comment.

Comment: I am inclined to start-closing questions about post ban criteria as opinion-based :) Most info we can provide is pure speculation with some clues scattered around the network. Re: your response to yivi - not sure I follow why would being able to review posts of others would entail an ability to write a good post. You wouldn't expect a film critic to automatically be a good director, do you? Anyways, it is commendable that you try to positively contribute despite the q-ban.

Comment: @OlegValter Because you rewrite a lot of stuff when doing review queues. That simple.

Comment: @CATboardBETA that’s not my experience. My experience is that questions that are duplicates **and** are poor (eg by not showing any evidence of research) are badly received. Duplicates that do show signs of research and are of good quality usually are not “downvoted significantly” before they are closed.

Comment: @yivi Well, it's not mine with my couple of duplicates or other duplicates I've seen on the site. *Maybe*, if they're really well written they'll get 1 or 2 points. But generally it's not the case.

Comment: @CATboardBETA I hate to be that guy, but this does not seem to be the case site-wise: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1384568/number-of-positively-received-closed-posts-to-total-closed-posts?Score=1. Nearly half of duped questions are positively received (and nearly all of them have at least 0-scored). Re: rewrites - still don't get why would it lead to improving question-asking skills. One can refactor a lot of code, but be none the wiser how to write better code - if they do good, it is because they are knowledgeable, not because they rewrote a thousand apps.

Comment: In any case, it is not my intention to argue for the sake of arguing - every positive contribution is appreciated, of course - we just don't know if it helps you to lift the ban or not. P.s. One piece of advice that might be useful to you - avoid posting answers to basic questions and especially to ones that already have a negative score [unless you are damn sure this is a hidden gem] - it is likely to be deleted with the question either automatically or manually, so your contribution will simply go to waste.

Comment: @OlegValter That data doesn't include deleted posts (as far as I know), so votes of remaining questions don't mean much for this topic when they maybe only represent a small percentage of all closed dupe questions.

Comment: @OlegValter To emphasize Tom's point, unless you're counting deleted posts, your query is actively biased towards only finding the dupes that were positively received, and says very little about how many dupes are poorly received. I will say that in my experience, reasonably asked questions are downvoted if they are dupes. And I'm not referring to blatant dupes even. I've frequently seen questions receive downvotes *after* a target is suggested, implying to me that the downvotes are *because* it's a dupe (standard caveat applies: I can't be sure why users downvote anything).

Comment: @CATboardBeta - A couple (more than 2 but less than 4) poorly received questions wouldn’t result in a question ban. How many deleted questions do you have? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65855696/how-to-implement-radical-equations-into-python) was poorly received due to the fact you didn’t make any attempt to show what you tried.  So it was downvoted due to the fact it contained no attempt (code) not because it was a duplicate

Comment: @Tom - well, yeah, I do know it does not include deleted questions, but, firstly, as you likely know, the PostsWithDeleted is not useful for these types of queries due to a lack of the ClosedDate column. Secondly, posts that are closed then deleted are either of poor quality (`RemoveAbandonedClosed` Roomba's rule excludes duplicates from the list of eligible "closed" questions, but there is a `RemoveDeadQuestions` rule, so I am not sure) or there is a much bigger systemic problem of deletion of good content (which I would appreciate having data about site-wide).

Comment: @OlegValter You're generally correct, yes, but there are also other reason why someone thought a delete vote is warranted (Q doesn't add new things to work as a signpost, for example), so we can only assume why such questions got deleted. So don't really know how many deleted question there are, how they were received, why they there received like that and why they were deleted. What I try to say is: looking into the database doesn't really provide us a clear picture for this specific question. But I appreciate your effort there.

Comment: @Tom - although I stand by the notion that inspecting what is publicly available does give us insight into how many posts closed as duplicates are downvoted (in contrast to just claiming that someone's personal experience means the matters are the same site-wide), I do understand your and cigien's issue with the data on closed questions since I agree that we do not know what's going on in the deleted part. I would love to get my hands on such a data to analyse, but alas...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing that will truly help you get out of a question ban is improving your questions so they get upvoted. Same thing goes for question bans, answer bans, etc - the only thing that'll get you out of an answer ban is improving your answers.

In fact, by posting this Meta question, you are on your way to getting out of a ban, because the Meta effect will draw attention to your questions and either get them upvoted or get you suggestions to improve them. That's how I got out of my question ban, actually.

Looking at your downvoted questions, all I can tell you is to ask a more specific question - instead of just asking "How do I do this?" ask "I tried to do this, but that happened instead. How do I fix my code?" Also provide a minimal reproducible example of course.

Good answers contribute a tiny amount to a question ban, but not enough that it'll get you out of the ban. Everything else contributes little or not at all to your question ban.

Comment: I find your second paragraph quite enlightening... I never really thought about even the idea of a Meta questions causing your account to get attention (Meta Effect). It almost feels like it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Or dig oneself deeper as the Meta Effect can turn both ways (but for now seems all is well in this case). Just wanted to warn readers that drawing attention on Meta could backfire.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Drawing attention to my very bad question (for feedback purposes) granted me a decent amount of downvotes, and a question ban (again).